# Understand Single Responsibility Principle of SOLID design

Tags: c#, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I'm currently trying to learn the SOLID design principles along with behavior driven development, but am having quite the hard time getting my head around the Single Responsibility Principle.  I've tried to find a good tutorial for c# that uses test driven development, but haven't been able to find anything worthwhile in that vein.  Anyway, after spending a few days reading about it, I decided the best way to learn is by experience, so I started creating a small app using those principles best I can.

It's a simple bowling score calculator.  I figured the best way to go about it was to work from the simplest part up, so I started at the ball (or throw) level.  Right now I have created tests and an interface and class for dealing with ball(throw) scores, which makes sure they aren't invalid, ie. `<10` or `>0`.  After implementing this I realized that the ball class is basically just a nullable integer, so maybe I don't even need it... but for now it's there.

Following the ball, I decided the next logical thing to add was a frame interface and class.  This is where I have gotten stuck.  Here is where I'm at:

```
namespace BowlingCalc.Frames
{
    public interface IFrame : BowlingCalc.Generic.ICheckValid
    {
        void AddThrow(int? score);
        int? GetThrow(int throw_number);
    }
}

namespace BowlingCalc.Frames
{
    public class Frame : IFrame
    {
        private List<Balls.IBall> balls;
        private Balls.IBall ball;
        private int frame_number;

        public Frame(Balls.IBall ball, int frame_number)
        {
            this.ball = ball;
            this.frame_number = frame_number;
            balls = new List<Balls.IBall>();
            check_valid();
        }

        public void AddThrow(int? score)
        {
            var current_ball = ball;
            current_ball.Score = score;
            balls.Add(current_ball);
        }

        public int? GetThrow(int throw_number)
        {
            return balls[throw_number].Score;
        }

        public void check_valid()
        {
            if (frame_number < 0 || frame_number > 10)
            {
                throw (new Exception("InvalidFrameNumberException"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The frame uses my previously implemented ball class through dependency injection to add ball scores to the frame.  It also implements a way to return the score for any given ball in the frame.

What I want to do, and where I'm stuck, is I want to add a way to make sure the frame score is valid. (For the moment just the simple case of frames 1-9, where the combined score of both balls must be 10 or less.  I will move on to the  much more complicated frame 10 case later.)

The problem is I have no idea how to implement this in a SOLID way.  I was thinking of adding the logic into the class, but that seems to go against the single responsibility principle.  Then I thought to add it as a separate interface/class and then call that class on each frame when its score updates.  I also thought of creating a separate interface, `IValidator` or something like that, and implementing that in the Frame class.  Unfortunately, I have no idea which, if any, of these is the best/SOLID way of doing things.

So, what would be a good, SOLID way to implement a method that validates the score of a frame?

---

Note: Any critique of my code is very welcome.  I am very excited learn to create better code, and happy to receive any help given.

Comment: This is one of the best readings about SOLID. It doesn't have much code, but it will help you with your decision - https://adevait.com/software/solid-design-principles-the-guide-to-becoming-better-developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of `ICheckValid` interface? Do you call `check_valid` elsewhere? In my opinion, since the `frame_number` seems to be in fact a read-only property of a `Frame`, why it would be wrong to verify its consistency right in the constructor without any additional interfaces for that? (Constructors are supposed to produce *consistent* objects and are thus free to validate incoming parameters however they like.)

However, rather than to ask how to properly validate this field, it might be better to ask why indeed you need the `frame_number` property in the `Frame`? It seems like this is an index of this item in some array - you may just use the index, why store it in the `Frame`? You may want to write some if/else logic later, such as:

```
if (frame_number == 10) {
     // some rules
} else {
     // other rules
}
```

However, this is unlikely a SOLID approach as you would probably end up writing this if/else statements in many parts of the `Frame`. Rather, you may create a base class `FrameBase`, define much of the logics there plus some abstract methods to be implemented in `OrdinaryFrame` and `TenthFrame`, where you would define different rules. This would enable you to avoid `frame_number` altogether -- you would just create nine `OrdinaryFrames` and one `TenthFrame`.

As for critique: your code seems to abstract balls and frames, but ignores 'throws', or 'rolls' for some reason. Consider a need to add trajectory information of each roll, you would need to change the `IFrame` interface, adding something like `void SetThrowTrajectory(int throwNumber, IThrowTrajectory trajectory)`. However, if you abstract throws away in an e.g. `IBallRoll`, the trajectory-related functionality would easily fit there (as well as some Boolean computed properties, e.g. `IsStrike`, `IsSpare`).

Comment: Wow, thanks!  That really is a lot of good advice, particularly about using a base frame class and inheriting from it to create the normal frame and then frame classes.  That is wonderful advice.

Comment: Related, for the frame validation, you are totally right, there is no need for a frame number at all, I was definitely over thinking it there.

Comment: As for the throws abstraction.  I apologize, I realized that my balls class is inappropriately named.  It really should be called throw or ballroll, as that is its purpose, to keep track of throw information, not ball information.  So it actually is that abstraction you were talking about.

Comment: Finally, what I really want to validate in the frame class is that the number of pins knocked down for the two throws for a normal frame doesn't go over 10.  For example, when throw 1 gets 4 pins, 2 gets 5, the frame is valid, but when throw 1 gets 6 and then throw 2 gets 5, the frame raises an exception.  This is what I'm really having trouble figuring out how to implement in a SOLID way.

Comment: Regarding `ICheckValid`, yeah, I use it in the poorly named IBall interface and class to check if the throw score is valid, as in between 0 and 10.  Though I have since realized that once I implement the validation checking I spoke of above, it will probably render the ball/throw checking redundant.

Comment: The problem to consider is -- when to call validation? An `ICheckValid` approach may result in seriously misplaced exceptions. I would recommend throwing an exception as early as possible. If score is inappropriate to add -- then throw exception right away, why would you want to change the object into an incorrect state and wait for some external forces to run validation upon that state?

Answer (score 3):

When I think SRP, I tend to put the emphasis on the Responsibility aspect.  The name of the class, in turn, should ideally describe its Responsibility.  For some classes this is about what the class is supposed to 'be' (a Frame could be a good example if it lacks behavior and merely represents state), but when you have a behavioral responsibility, the name is about what the class is supposed to 'do'.

Computing scores by itself is a fairly small responsibility, so let's consider something slightly larger and more naturally decomposable.  Here is one possible breakdown of a bowling game with simple responsibilities and with suitably paranoid encapsulation (we're all friends here, but nobody wants anybody to cheat by mistake.)

```
//My job is to keep score; I don't interpret the scores
public interface IScoreKeeper : IScoreReporter
{
    void SetScore(int bowlerIndex, int frameIndex, int throwIndex, int score);
}

//My job is to report scores to those who want to know the score, but shouldn't be allowed to change it
public interface IScoreReporter
{
    int? GetScore(int bowlerIndex, int frameIndex, int throwIndex);        
}

//My job is to play the game when told that it's my turn
public interface IBowler
{
    //I'm given access to the ScoreReporter at some point, so I can use that to strategize
    //(more realisically, to either gloat or despair as applicable)

    //Throw one ball in the lane, however I choose to do so
    void Bowl(IBowlingLane lane);
}

//My job is to keep track of the pins and provide score feedback when they are knocked down
//I can be reset to allow bowling to continue
public interface IBowlingLane
{
    int? GetLastScore();

    void ResetLane();
}

//My job is to coordinate a game of bowling with multiple players
//I tell the Bowlers to Bowl, retrieve scores from the BowlingLane and keep
//the scores with the ScoreKeeper.
public interface IBowlingGameCoordinator
{
    //In reality, I would probably have other service dependencies, like a way to send feedback to a monitor
    //Basically anything that gets too complicated and can be encapsulated, I offload to some other service to deal with it
    //I'm lazy, so all I want to do is tell everybody else what to do.

    void PlayGame(IScoreKeeper gameScore, IEnumerable<IBowler> bowlers, IBowlingLane lane);
}
```

Note that if you wanted to use this model to simply compute scores (without playing a real game), you can have a stub Bowler (who does nothing) and a MockBowlingLane, who produces a series of score values.  The BowlingGameCoordinator takes care of the current bowler, frame and throw, so the scores get accumulated.

Comment: Thank you for the great response.  It is a little high level for me at the moment.  Right now I just want to focus on the scoring portion, but this gives me a lot to think about and a good test for extending my scorer once I have it finished.

Comment: The approach described by @Dan Bryant is sometimes criticized for being overly procedural, e.g. http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html . (The problem is that you may end up with one-method classes basically no better than global procedures). However, it still may be useful, and is in fact widely used.